# Sencha Touch 2 share events between the views and controllers

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I what to share some events from my application to be shared across the views and controllers.
For example, event: "updates from server are available".
To do that I can fireEvent("updatesAvailable") in the controller, but that makes other components to subscribe to that particular controller that fires that event.

What I want is to have a singleton object that will keep all application logic events subscriptions.

Currently I see that I can solve the problem with having one shared view instance and subscribe all to it. But I would like to know is there is one out of the box Event Dispatcher that is aware about all events inside the application.

Comment: as my practice, I always create a controller called `GlobalController.js`, put all "global" events listeners there, and in corresponding handlers, call necessary functions of others, e.g: `Ext.getApplication().getController('controller_1').function_1()`, `Ext.getApplication().getController('controller_2').function_2()`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to use pattern 'Event Bus'?
You could use the 'global' and single object that exists in every ST2 application - Ext.Viewport. At least I'm creating in my app and till now nothing is bad.
Note, the best place to create event handler is controller's init() method.

```
Ext.define('Myapp.controller.ActivitiesController', {

extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

requires : [],
    config: {
        refs: {
            myview: 'myview'
        }
...
    init: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.Viewport.on({
        scope: this,
        addactivitytype: function (config) {
                    var myview = me.getMyview(),
                        record = config.record
...

          });
     }
});
```

in the another controller (or ever view) you could write

```
 addActivityTypeTap: function (record) {
      ....
      Ext.Viewport.fireEvent('addactivitytype', {
        record: record
      });
 }
```